# Which SQLite.Ado.Net package to use?

Tags: vb.net, system.data.sqlite

Now that the SQLite.Ado.Net project has moved from [Phoenix Software Solutions](http://sqlite.phxsoftware.com) to the [SQLite team](http://system.data.sqlite.org/index.html/doc/trunk/www/index.wiki), there are several different [packages available](http://system.data.sqlite.org/index.html/doc/trunk/www/downloads.wiki) for each version of the .Net framework:

- Setups: Includes design-time component for VS 2005, and Visual C++ 2005 SP1 runtime
- Precompiled Binaries:  The Visual C++ 2012 RTM runtime is not included
- Precompiled Statically-Linked: The Visual C++ 2005 SP1 runtime for x86 is statically linked

Each package is available in two versions:

- bundle = "mixed-mode assembly + all the binaries"; mixed-mode assembly only necessary when the binary assembly must be installed in the GAC
- no-bundle = "all the binaries"

Which package should I download for...

- a developer host working with VB.Net Express
- a user host running a VB.Net application
  ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

You can use this link for solve your problem: [ADO.NET 2.0 Provider](http://sourceforge.net/projects/sqlite-dotnet2/files/SQLite%20for%20ADO.NET%202.0/1.0.66.0/)